# How to customize zurb foundation framework's label or alert boxes with mixin

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm new to web development and css. I like the grid layout in zurb foundation framework and figured out how to use it for my rails app. How can I customize some of the scss properties? On zurb foundation's site they refer to the concept of a mixin. I'm not sure how to use that in my override.css.scss file. Here is an example of what they show on their site:

```
$include-html-alert-classes: $include-html-classes;

// We use this to control alert padding.
$alert-padding-top: rem-calc(11);
$alert-padding-default-float: $alert-padding-top;
$alert-padding-opposite-direction: $alert-padding-top + rem-calc(10);
$alert-padding-bottom: $alert-padding-top + rem-calc(1);

// We use these to control text style.
$alert-font-weight: bold;
$alert-font-size: rem-calc(14);
$alert-font-color: #fff;
$alert-font-color-alt: scale-color($secondary-color, $lightness: -66%);
```

Following the above description on their site, they have an example of a custom alert property:

```
.custom-alert-box {
  @include alert(
    // Adjust the background of the alert
    $bg: #cccccc,
    // Give a border to the alert box
    $radius: true
  );
}
```

How can I modify this? How do I know what goes in `@include alert`? Where is this option of using  `@include alert` even specified? using `$bg` and `$radius: true` works in this custom configuration, where can I get the additional properties from? I tried plugging in `$alert-font-weight: bold;` inside the custom-alert-box but that doesnt seem to work. Could someone explain the gist of customizing these properties. Thank you in advance and sorry for the noob question.

Comment: the best is to go through foundation's [Sass files](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/tree/master/scss/foundation) and familiarize yourself with the mixins. Here are the mixins and variables controlling the alerts: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_alert-boxes.scss. Seems like the `alert` mixin that you are including only takes the two arguments, but you can control other stuff through variables or add in your custom mixin.